# Convert .json to .csv

Tags: json, syntax, jq, export-to-csv

jq version jq-1.6 on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTE

Looking to convert large .json file to .csv

json example:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5200a366e36f237975000783"},"derived_form":{"$numberInt":"1"},"intransitive":true,"lemma":"badbad","phonetic":"bɐdbɐt","pos":"VERB","root":{"radicals":"b-d-b-d"},"sources":["Spagnol2011","Falzon2013"],"glosses":[{"gloss":"to fornicate","examples":[]},{"gloss":"to cough a lot","examples":[]}],"norm_freq":{"$numberDouble":"0.0"}}
```

How do I convert to .csv:

`5200a366e36f237975000783, badbad, bɐdbɐt, VERB, true, b-d-b-d, "to fornicate, to cough a lot"`

```
jq '.lemma, .phonetic, .pos, .intransitive, .root.radicals, .glosses.[].gloss'
```

throws an error in Ubuntu but not at jqplay.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain the desired csv output:

```bash
$ jq -r '"\(._id[]), \(.lemma), \(.phonetic), \(.pos), \(.intransitive), \(.root.radicals), \"\([.glosses[].gloss] | join(","))\""' file
5200a366e36f237975000783, badbad, bɐdbɐt, VERB, true, b-d-b-d, "to fornicate,to cough a lot"
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> jq '.lemma, .phonetic, .pos, .intransitive, .root.radicals, .glosses.[].gloss'`
> ```
>
> throws an error in Ubuntu but not at jqplay.org

Your Ubuntu machine is probably not using jq 1.7, which is the version currently running on [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/). This version introduced a new syntax, which you are using with `.glosses.[]`. From the [release info](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/releases):

> Allow dot for chained value iterator `.[]`, `.[]?` [@wader](https://github.com/wader) [#2650](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/pull/2650)
>
> ```bash
> $ jq -n '{"a": [123]} | .a[]'
> 123
> # now this also works
> $ jq -n '{"a": [123]} | .a.[]'
> 123
> ```

Thus, change your approach to use `.glosses[]` instead:

```bash
jq '.lemma, .phonetic, .pos, .intransitive, .root.radicals, .glosses[].gloss'
```